# pd.merge is adding extra rows, duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, merge

While merging two df, it seems to be adding duplicates rows some how.

I do need to keep the exactly number of rows of db in the left.

data:

```
# main data
df = pd.DataFrame({ "campaign_name": ["111","222","333"], "leads": [1, 2, 1] })

# reff table
dim_campaign = pd.DataFrame({ "campaign_name": ["111","222","333"], "Type": ["a", "b" , "c"] })


# counting number leads
df.campaign_name.value_counts()
```

my code:

#### The problem is.. after merging and verify number of rows has increase. I do want keep all the original rows of "df" and just add the info of columns that matches.

```
df = df.groupby("campaign_name")["leads"].sum()


df = pd.merge(df, dim_campaign[["campaign_name", "Type"]],on='campaign_name', how='left')


x =df.loc[df.campaign_name=="222"]
x.leads.sum()

# it gives a higher value
```

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your problem and I can't - I see 3 rows in your merged and unmerged dataframes. Can you elaborate?

Comment: So the df is huge, like 500 thousand rows.. it was just example. So what I believe is happening is.. while merging it is keeping the values from df and reff table. Did it helps?

Comment: have you tried doing df.drop_duplicates()?

Comment: also, I'm wondering whether an "inner join" wouldn't be better suited? An inner join would ensure that only matches are merged.

Comment: I havent tried drop duplicates.. I will now.
About Inner join.. would it keep rows on left that wont match.. Because I need to keep everything on left ?

Comment: inner joins the intersection of both sets, so I don't think it's what you're looking for, come to think of it. Drop duplicates is therefore the best fit, I think.

Comment: Worked!! there was duplicates at the reff sheet, you can post the answer, thank you for helping..

Comment: Your question as it stands doesn't match with the answer, since obviously there will not be duplicates there.

Comment: thanks, will fix it, by the time I asked I didnt knew the problem

Comment: duplicates suggests there is some logical error so be cautious. i also don't think there is problem with merge or join. my be your group by which is using "leads" instead of "campaign_name" impacting your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

To remove duplicates from a left or right join.